# “Error: could not find chaincode” occurs when execute composer runtime install

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We're thinking about migration from Hyperledger Composer v0.13.0 to the latest one (v0.16.5), so I have tried  to create and deploy business network according tutorial below.
 https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial
But at the Step 4, `composer runtime install` command doesn't work.

Here is the error occured.

```
✖ Installing runtime for business network <<MY_BUSINESS_NETWORK>>. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: could not find chaincode with name '<<MY_BUSINESS_NETWORK>>' - make sure the chaincode <<MY_BUSINESS_NETWORK>> has been successfully instantiated and try again
Command failed
```

But I'm not sure where instantiation should be done.
I guess that `composer runtime install` and `composer network start` are counterparts of `composer network deploy` in v0.13.0, but is it wrong? In v0.13.0, I didn't need to execute "instantiate" command explicitly.

I would appreciate any suggestions or information, thanks.

My procedure

```
 1. prepare credentials,channenl-artifacts and connection profile then start dockers.
 2. create channel and make peers joined.
 3. create BNA & card Files.
 4. import the card of PeerAdmin then confirm with composer card list command.
 5. execute composer install runtime command.
```

Environment

```
Ubuntu : 16.04
hyperledger composer : 0.16.5
ibmblockchain/fabric-tools     1.0.5   
ibmblockchain/fabric-ca        1.0.5
ibmblockchain/fabric-peer      1.0.5
ibmblockchain/fabric-orderer   1.0.5
ibmblockchain/fabric-couchdb   1.0.5
```

Comment: additionaly, I'd had misunderstanding about the role PeerAdmin so I'd executed `composer card create` with `--businessNetworkName` option.  I got an error below in ca log. it seems that `composer runtime install ` command tried to query to ca's DB but user PeerAdmin that not existed. 
```
 [DEBUG] Directing traffic to CA <<MY_CA>>
 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity PeerAdmin
 [DEBUG] Failed to get identity 'PeerAdmin': sql: no rows in result set ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the runtime install and network start (as you correctly understood) are two separate tasks that are likely to be performed by a Peer administrator and a network administrator (two separate roles) and hence why they are broken out - demarcation of duty. network deploy is deprecated from old days.

On tutorial - I suggest to do a 'teardown' from the `fabric-tools` directory and clear out your $HOME/.composer cards directory.  I assume you downloaded a new fabric tools afresh? Did you also make sure to update your pre-requisites if/as required per the documentation https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

The error you posted related to << MY_BUSINESS NETWORK >> I assume, is because you've obfuscated the real network name - understandable) otherwise is an unusual error and not the name given in the tutorial - if you follow the tutorial it should deployed as follows (ie cut and paste from tutorial):

runtime install:

```
composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network
```

network start:

```
composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card
```

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html and this has been working fine for ages.

Are you trying to build your own Fabric network, single-org or multi-org, on same virtual host or across different physical/virtual machines ? Because the Fabric Dev server setup provided by Composer does 1 and 2 for you. You can also create the PeerAdmin card for that, as instructed in our docs (run a script).

Based on your procedure I would add first:

1. Do a teardown and remove old cards (as mentioned above)
2. do your steps 1 and 2 (and then create your Fabric network if that's what you want to do)

After your [custom] Fabric is up and running:
step 3. Test your custom Fabric Network to validate the configuration using the Fabric marbles sample chaincode. If that works, proceed to build your own PeerAdmin card
step 4. deploy the Business network by installing Composer runtime on all peers first then doing a network start of the bna on the channel you configured
step 5. Create Composer BN cards, connection profiles, identities and participants etc

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer. As you mentioned, I'd tried with my own network and apparently that caused the trouble.  I found that tls is not enabled in network but I I'd tried to execute `composer card create` with tls. `composer card create` without tls make it works, thank you.